# What's the corresponding command of `CTRL-Y` and `CTRL-E`?

Tags: vimscript, lua

As title. I know that I can just press `CTRL-Y/E` to scroll, but now I need to use a script to execute them. What are the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<C-y>` is `<C-y>` and `<C-e>` is `<C-e>`. They *are* the commands. There is no "corresponding command".

To execute a normal mode command in a scripting context, use `:help :normal`:

```
normal ^Y
```

with `^Y` obtained by pressing `<C-v>`, then `<C-y>`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the clean answer! I thought `CTRL-Y` were `scroll-up` and it failed... Then wrongly assumed that I typed the wrong one.

Comment: Again, and again… don't "think" or "assume". Don't act out of ignorance, act out of knowledge. `:help user-manual`.